# Status Text need be display as true React

Tags: reactjs

I am getting output correctly as JSON format. I need to display in this `td` column if the status is 1, I need to display it as true, otherwise false.

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => await Load())();
}, []);

async function Load() {
  const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/tasks");
  setTasks(result.data);
  console.log(result);
}
```

Result displayed in json format

```
 {
   "_id": "64ad2fd352f8f6937e4bb6af",
   "title": "task1",
   "description": "task1 sf",
   "duedate": "2023-12-02T18:30:00.000Z",
   "status": "1",
   "__v": 0
 },
```

What I tried so far I attached below. I am getting result as `{task.duedate}` this way. I need if result is 1, I need to display it as true and the text color needs to be changed as green

```
<td class="px-6 py-4">
   {
     if (task.status === "1") {
        //...
     }
     else {
        //...
     }
   }
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on `task.status` you return the coresponding `<span>`

```js
<td className="px-6 py-4">
  {task.status === "1" ? (
    <span style={{ color: "green" }}>true</span>
  ) : (
    <span>false</span>
  )}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<td class="px-6 py-4">
   {task.status === '1' ? <span style={{color:'green'}}>true</span> : <span style={{color:'red'}}>false</span>}
</td>
```